# C#.NET Getting File Replaced Time

Tags: c#, file, replace

When we upload files from browser if there's a file with same name in directory, it'll overwrite the existing one.

Is there any way (any property) I can check the last replace time for the file...?

Any suggesting will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks n Regard,
Aki

Answer (score 2):

Are you just asking for the modified timestamp on the file, like this?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo("C:\\foo.txt");
        Console.WriteLine(fileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc);
    }
}
```